# Torque for uniform rectangular plate

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, torque

> A uniform rectangular plane lamina of mass m and dimensions a and b (assume b > a) rotates with the constant angular velocity ω about a diagonal. Ignoring gravity, find:
>
> a) principal axes and moments of inertia;
>
> b) angular momentum vector in the body coordinate system;
>
> c) external torque necessary to sustain such rotation.
>
> [image: The rotating plate]

I have a brief question concerning problem c). In the solutions they write that the torque is $\vec{\theta}=\frac{d \vec{L}}{dt}+\vec{\omega} \times \vec{L}$. They then go on and say that $\frac{d \vec{L}}{dt}=0$ because the questions asks to sustain the rotation.The problem is that I don't know how they get the term $\vec{\omega} \times \vec{L}$. It's probably pretty simple, but I don't see it at the moment. Normally, I define the torque to be $\vec{\theta}= \vec{r} \times \vec{F}$.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torque has alternative definitions

Comment: What did you look into to try to figure this out?

Comment: Newton's second law for rotation: $\vec{\theta}=I\times \vec{\alpha}$ with $I$ the inertial moment about that specific axis and $\vec{\alpha}$ the angular acceleration. With  $\vec{\alpha}=0 \implies \vec{\theta}=0$.

Comment: Actually the first problem is that I don't know why an external torque is necessary at all. Would it have a precession motion because it is not rotating about one of its principal axis of inertia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation that you're trying to use,
$$
\vec{\theta}=\frac{d \vec{L}}{dt}+\vec{\omega} \times \vec{L}
$$
is called [Euler's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_equations_(rigid_body_dynamics)).<sup>1</sup>  Importantly, **Euler's equation only holds in a rotating reference frame,** where $\vec{\omega}$ is the angular velocity of the rotating frame relative to some inertial frame.

The body's coordinate system is, of course, a rotating reference frame.  In the body's reference frame, $\vec{\omega}$ is fixed, and the moment of inertia tensor is fixed, so therefore $\vec{L} = \mathbf{I} \vec{\omega}$ is also fixed.  Thus, in this reference frame, $d\vec{L}/dt = 0$.

However, this equation does imply that a torque will be necessary to maintain a rotation about an arbitrary axis.  It is instructive to look at this equation and see what the torque would be if you rotated this along a principal axis as opposed to an arbitrary axis.  (HINT:  what is the relationship between $\vec{\omega}$ and $\vec{L}$ if $\vec{\omega}$ is along a principal axis?)

---

<sup>1</sup>  Actually, it's one of several equations called "Euler's equation".  Euler was a prolific guy.  Whenever you start feeling too proud of yourself, compare yourself to Euler.

Comment: That Euler Wit was hilarious! ^^